# C# XNA - How to create a menu with bools and textures?

Tags: xna, c#, textures, menu

I thought I could use `bools` to be able to select options in my menu. But the options should be textures. To show that an optino is selected I have 2 textures like this:

```
[----Menu Screen----]
 [  >  Option1  <  ] Option1 = Start Game
 [     Option2     ] Option2 = Options
 [     Option3     ] Option3 = Exit
[----Menu Screen----]
```

So the `>` and `<` are the textures I'm using to show the user that he has selected an option. I have the following code:

```
enum gameStates
{
    gameLoading,
    mainMenu,
    gameOptions,
    levelSelect,
    gamePlaying,
    gameOver,
}
gameStates CurrentGameState = gameStates.gameLoading;
```

And maybe using `bools` like this may work?

```
// gameStates.mainMenu bools
bool startGameSelected = true;
bool optionsSelected = false;
bool exitSelected = false;
```

`Update()` method:

```
    switch (CurrentGameState)
        {
    // gameStates.gameLoading here...

    // gameStates.mainMenu:
            case gameStates.mainMenu:
if (startGameSelected)
                    {
                        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                        {
                            CurrentGameState = gameStates.levelSelect;
                        }
                    }
                    if (optionsSelected)
                    {
                        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                        {
                            CurrentGameState = gameStates.gameOptions;
                        }
                    }
                    if (exitSelected)
                    {
                        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                        {
                            this.Exit();
                        }
                    }
                    if (startGameSelected) 
                    {
                        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                        {
                        exitSelected = true;
                        optionsSelected = false;
                        startGameSelected = false;
                        }

                        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                        {
                        startGameSelected = false;
                        exitSelected = false;
                        optionsSelected = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (optionsSelected)
                    {
                        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                        {
                            startGameSelected = true;
                            exitSelected = false;
                            optionsSelected = false;
                        }
                        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                        {
                            exitSelected = true;
                            optionsSelected = false;
                            startGameSelected = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (exitSelected)
                    {
                       if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                       {
                           optionsSelected = true;
                           exitSelected = false;
                           startGameSelected = false;
                       }
                        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                        {
                            startGameSelected = true;
                            exitSelected = false;
                            optionsSelected = false;
                        }
                    }
```

`Draw()` method:

```
switch (CurrentGameState)
        {
    // gameStates.gameLoading here...

    // gameStates.mainMenu:
            case gameStates.mainMenu:
    // Draw the startGame button
         spriteBatch.Draw(startGameTexture, startGamePosition, Color.White);
                // Draw the exitGame button
         spriteBatch.Draw(exitGameTexture, exitGamePosition, Color.White);
                // Draw the gameOptions button
         spriteBatch.Draw(gameOptinonsTexture, gameOptionsPosition, Color.White);
                // Draw the ">" and "<" arrows
         if (startGameSelected)
         {
             spriteBatch.Draw(redArrowTexture, new Vector2(280, 320), Color.White);
             spriteBatch.Draw(greenArrowTexture, new Vector2(484, 320), Color.White);
         }
```

But for some strange reason it seems this won't work any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that only one item can be selected at a time, it would be better to store the index of the selected item (possibly as an `enum`, for clarity - you can cast between an enumeration and an `int`), rather than using a mess of Booleans.

That way you can:

- Move through the menu with `++` and `--`
- Detect that the selected item has gone out of range, use the `%` operator to implement wrapping
- Use a `select` statement to select an appropriate action to take when activating the selected menu item
- Use a single `Draw` statement to draw your selection cursor textures, use simple maths to calculate their position based on which item is selected

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Andrew Russell! I'd prefer `enum`. But anyway could I have an example code? Then I'll mark this as the answer of this question.

Comment: I'd rather not - this is a Q&A site, not a "write my code for me" site, after all. The code is fairly trivial, though, so why don't you give it a go? If you have any trouble, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: OK so something like this: I create the `enum` and then I put its `switch` statemant in the `CurrentGameState switch`, `case gameStates.mainMenu` in the `Update()` and `Draw()` method? And maybe use `if()` statements for the loginc? Also you're right I just need to plan the code in my mind and when I type it everything should be alright. If I succeed I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Charlie Use `switch(selectedMenuItem) { ... }` where you need to. But try and use maths like `new Vector2(xOffset, yOffset + (int)selectedMenuItem * lineHeight)` where possible. (Obviously these go with something like `enum MenuItem { ... }` and `MenuItem selectedMenuItem;`.)

Comment: Done. Used `if()` statements again to add the `Update()` logic but the when changing `Start Game` to `Options` it directly flips to `Exit`. Just one more suggestion and I accept this answer.

Comment: That's a problem with your code. Use the debugger to step through it and see if what it's doing matches what you expect. Inspect the values at they change in Watch window. Use "find all references" to locate all the places that your variable could be being modified.